# I just created an extremely fast way to sort primes. How do I improve it?

Tags: c++

Basically, how it works is it converts a number into a string, and if it finds any even in the string then it gives `foundEven` variable a positive value. The same goes for odd numbers.

(One thing I don't get is why if I switch the '>' sign with an '<' in `if (FoundEvenSignedInt < FoundOddSignedInt)` it gives you the correct result of an odd number.)

Are there any ways I could improve the code? Are there any bugs in it? I'm fairly new at C++ programing.

```
#include <string>
#include <cstddef>

int IsPrime(long double a)
{
    int var;
    long double AVar = a;
    signed int FoundEvenSignedInt, FoundOddSignedInt;
    std::string str = std::to_string(a);
    std::size_t foundEven = str.find_last_of("2468");
    std::size_t foundOdd = str.find_last_of("3579");
    FoundEvenSignedInt = foundEven;
    FoundOddSignedInt = foundOdd;
    if (FoundEvenSignedInt < FoundOddSignedInt)
    {
        var = 1;
        goto EndOfIsPrimeFunction;
    }
    if (FoundEvenSignedInt > FoundOddSignedInt)
    {
        var = 2;
        goto EndOfIsPrimeFunction;
    }
    // This if statement kept giving me this weird warning so I made it like this
    if (FoundEvenSignedInt == -1)
    {
        if (FoundOddSignedInt == -1)
        {
            if (AVar == 10 || 100 || 1000 || 10000 || 100000 || 1000000)
            {
                var = 2;
                goto EndOfIsPrimeFunction;
            }
        }
    }
EndOfIsPrimeFunction:
          return var;
}
```

Comment: I think this belongs on Code Review.

Comment: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I'm really wondering though, if there is any particular reason to use those `goto` statements when you can simply do `return`... However, it indeed does not belong to Stack Overflow.

Comment: "extremely fast way to sort primes" Nice! Where can we find it?

Comment: What is the connection between the Collatz Conjecture and the prime numbers? What exactly is that function supposed to do? (I can't see anything to do with primes or sorting.) Are you aware that `AVar == 10 || 100 || 1000 || 10000 || 100000 || 1000000` is true for all values of `AVar`?

Comment: @molbdnilo I needed a way to tell if a number was prime to see if I had to divide by 2 or *3+1.

Comment: "Are you aware that AVar == 10 || 100 || 1000 || 10000 || 100000 || 1000000 is true for all values of AVar" Why is that? @molbdnilo

Comment: Run the above function and find out @n.m.

Comment: @Imperator The compiler kept on spitting out warnings when I put more than one `return` statement.

Comment: @Bored For the Collatz Conjecture you need to know whether numbers are even or odd, not if they're prime, and your function has nothing to do with primality anyway. What is the point of `IsPrime(1.25) == 1` or `IsPrime(11.1) == 11`?

Comment: @molbdnilo Oh Shit! I just googled "prime number" and what popped up was "When a number has more than two factors it is called a composite number. Here are the first few prime numbers: 2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29, 31, 37, 41, 43, 47, 53, 59, 61, 67, 71, 73, 79, 83, 89, 97, 101, 103, 107, 109, 113, 127, 131, 137, 139, 149, 151, 157, 163, 167, 173, 179, 181, 191, 193, 197, 199, etc." I now realize this function only tells if a number is even or odd

Comment: @bored It doesn't even do that since "odd" and "even", like primality, are properties of integers.

Comment: @molbdnilo I dare you to run the program and see if it "doesn't even do that" https://github.com/BoredBored/3A/blob/master/Collatz-conjectureAl.cpp

Comment: @Bored That's why you want to use `else if` instead of a cascade of plain `if` statements, so you don't have to put tons of unnecessary `goto` jumps. This is a very minor thing compared to other problems with this code as explained in other comments, of course.

Comment: @Bored The code you posted isn't the code you linked, but even in your linked code, [10 is odd](http://ideone.com/BUxsCC), which is very odd indeed.  Here's a slightly more efficient way of doing things : `bool is_odd(unsigned long x) { return x & 1; }`.

Comment: The posted code has nothing to do with sorting or prime numbers. or indeed with being fast.

Comment: Removed confusing intro

Answer (score 1):

Here are some ways to improve the code.

1. The Collatz conjecture is about integers. `long double` is a data type of floating point numbers. It is unsuitable for checking the conjecture. You need to work with an integral data type such as `unsigned long long`. If this doesn't have enough range for you, you need to work with some kind of [Bignum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arbitrary-precision_arithmetic) dat atype. There isn't any in the standard C library, you need to find a third party one.
2. The Collatz conjecture has nothing to do with being prime. It is about even and odd integers. It is true that all prime numbers except 2 are odd, but this fact doesn't help you.
3. The data type to answer yes/no questions in C++ is `bool`. By convention. for any other numeric data type zero means "no" and all other values mean "yes" (technically, when converted to `bool`, zero is converted to `false` and other values to `true`, so you can do things like `if (a % 2)`. A function that returns `1` and `2` for `yes` and `no` is highly unconventional.
4. A natural method of checking whether a number is odd is this:

   ```
   bool isOdd (unsigned long long a) 
   {
       return a % 2;
   }
   ```

   It is somewhat faster than your code (by a factor of about 400 on my computer), gives correct results every time, is readable, and has zero `goto` statements.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of the `if(AVar == 10 || 100 || ...`, you can say `if(!(AVar % 10))`.